# Locution "en grand"

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

> Malaparte, c'est bien savoureux, mais c'est du journalisme, en grand,
> en très grand.

Est-ce que la locution *en grand* / *en très grand* fait référence au style de Malaparte ? Dans ce cas, pourquoi *en grand* et non *du grand* ?

Comment: CNRTL + en grand Dans des proportions considérables, sur un vaste plan. Travailler en grand. Il fit l'usure en grand (Balzac, E. Grandet,1834, p. 232).On a fait, il y a quelques années, du népotisme en grand (Reybaud, J. Paturot,1842, p. 387).

Comment: Merci pour votre commentaire, Lambie. À mon humble avis, pourtant, il me semble que l'interpétation faite par @jiliagre est plus juste !

Comment: @ovide They're not at odds; Lambie's given the general meaning of the term and jlliagre's explained its usage in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

*Du grand, du très grand* serait élogieux et traduirait l'excellence.

*En grand, en très grand* l'est beaucoup moins. La formule est mitigée et évoque plus la taille, le volume de l'œuvre, sa limitation à une approche journalistique excluant des qualités plus littéraires.

Comment: Quite the witticism then...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, il y a une bonne dose d'ironie dans cette formule, un compliment qui fait mal...